# Не могу решить задачу на C++

Tags: c++, двумерный-массив

Нужно создать двумерный динамический массив и вывести в формате (строка, столбец) вывести номер строки и столбца значение которого строго больше заданного числа.

Я тестил и на вход подавал значения (3 3 10)
И каждый раз одно число у меня не проходило проверку. То есть при введенном числе max=10, у меня проверку проходило число -19. Помогите пожалуйста с решением данной проблемы

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void ViewElement(const int& size1, const int& size2, int** arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void AddElement2(const int& size1, const int& size2, int** arr, const int max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j]>max) 
                cout << "Строка: " << j << "   Колонна: " << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
void AddElement(const int& size1, const int& size2, int** arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++){
            arr[i][j] = rand()%100 - 50;
        }
            
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int size1, size2, max;
    cin >> size1 >> size2 >> max;
    int** arr = new int* [size1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[size2];
    }

    AddElement(size1, size2, arr);
    ViewElement(size1, size2, arr);
    cout << endl << endl;
    AddElement2(size1, size2, arr, max);

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: На будущее: код выделяется не одним обратным апострофом, как у вас, а тремя, снизу и сверху от кода.

Comment: В i и j перепутали местами при выводе. Строка у вас - i, а колонна - j.